# How do I get the rotation animation using the ViewController class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm not getting the rotation animation provided by the ViewController class.  I thought I set it up correctly but something is wrong because its not happening and in the debugger I only hit the breakpoint at the function shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation only once at startup but not when I rotate the device in the simulator.  Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

GLViewController.m

```
    #import "GLViewController.h"
    #import "GLView.h"

    @implementation GLViewController

    - (void)loadView {

        CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

        GLView *glView = [[[GLView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame] autorelease];
        self.view = glView;

    }

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // We can run in landscape mode
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize m_window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.m_window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
    //m_view = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame: screenBounds];
    m_viewController = [GLViewController alloc];
    [m_window addSubview:m_viewController.view];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.m_window addSubview: m_viewController.view];
    [self.m_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: This is probably not related to your problem, but you should use `[self.window setRootViewController:m_viewController]` instead of adding the controller's view as the window's subview.

Comment: you shouldn't be mixing the viewcontroller animation and opengl animation, or opengl in general. If you have to rotate a glview, do it with opengl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling init on your `GLViewController` instance. This could cause all kinds of strange behaviour, including (perhaps) the rotation callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.m_window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    m_viewController = [[GLViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];  
    self.m_window.rootViewController = m_viewController;
    [self.m_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to create UINavigationController's object and push your view controller(GLViewController) on it in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions". Add UINavigationController.view as a subview instead of view controller's view.